# How to take the derivative of an integral with an upper limit of integration not x?

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So using the fundamental theorem of calculus, I know that with a being a constant, the derivative of $\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ is just f(x). But what if the upper limit of integration is not x, but instead with something like 5x+2? or x squared?

So what would be the derivative of $\int_{a}^{5x+2} f(t)dt$ (a will always be a constant)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule